# Monogame Content Manager - WAV/MP3 Importer Terrible Final Quality

Tags: c#, xna, wav, monogame, wma

I'm developing a game in Monogame, and using the Content Manager to manage audio files used as background music. I have three tracks in `WAV` format. These are the settings I'm using for importing the tracks:

[image: Monogame screenshot]

The converted `WMA` files in the final build are significantly low quality. I've tried using `MP3` source files, but the same issue occurs.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? If the `WAV` importer will always compress and reduce quality this much, are there are any workarounds where I can add in the correct tracks after the build is completed?

Answer (score 0):

In my current project I use both mp3 and wav as source files and never run into such problems.
Does this occur with other files as well or only with your intro.wav?